# PHP if string exist in array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I'm having issues checking if the string exist in array after splitting a single string into array by comma. it keeps returning false here my code. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong in my code?

```
<?php

$myString = "10.0.0.1 , IP: 10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017 , IP: 10.0.0.3 Date: 05/07/2017";
$IPS = explode(' , ', $myString); 
$string = "10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017";

foreach ($IPS as $IP) 
{
if(in_array($string, $IP))
    {
        die('YES');
    }
    else
    {
        die('NO'); // keeps returning no when the $string is in the array.

    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Your array is `$IPS`, not `$IP`. `$IP` is the string of each element in the array.

Comment: `10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017` doesn't exist. It's `IP: 10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017` that does (you missed the leading `IP: `). `in_array()` matches the full values, not partials.

Comment: Do you compare two strings? Use `strpos`.

Comment: And as you `die`, you will never move after first element of array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to use `strpos` instead of looping through the array

```
<?php

$myString = "10.0.0.1 , IP: 10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017 , IP: 10.0.0.3 Date: 05/07/2017";
$string = "10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017";

if(strpos($myString, $string))
    {
        die('YES');
    }
    else
    {
        die('NO');
    } 

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two error with your code. First $IP is string not array, so your is_array is not appropriate. Second when the first element not have $string the process with exit with die("NO"), then the remain code will not execute.

Check the **[live demo](https://eval.in/788862)**.

```
<?php

$myString = "10.0.0.1 , IP: 10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017 , IP: 10.0.0.3 Date: 05/07/2017";
$IPS = explode(' , ', $myString); 
$string = "10.0.0.2 Date: 05/07/2017";

foreach ($IPS as $IP) 
{
if(strpos($IP, $string) !== FALSE)
    {
        die('YES');
    }
}
die('NO');
```